# Question about a statement in Mac Lane's "Categories for the working mathematician" about a bijection being natural in an object

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

I have a question about a statement in Mac Lane's "Categories for the working mathematician". It is in page 51, in the context of graphs and free categories.
The statement basically says:

Let $G$ be a graph, $C_G$ its associated free category and $p: G \to UC_G$ the canonical map where $U: \operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Grph}$ is the forgetful functor.
For any category $B$, we have a natural bijection (by the universal property of $C_G$) $\operatorname{Cat}(C_G,B) \cong \operatorname{Grph}(G,UB)$ given by $F: C_G \to B \mapsto UF \circ p$. (Here comes the part I have trouble with) Moreover, this bijection is natural in G and in B.

What I am not understanding is what does this last sentence mean in this context?

I tried to construct the most natural functors possible out of the maps $B \mapsto \operatorname{Cat}(C_G,B)$ and $B \mapsto \operatorname{Grph}(G,UB)$, which led, for example, to the functor $\operatorname{Grph}(G,U \bullet): \operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Cat}$, by defining a category structure in $\operatorname{Grph}(G,UB)$, (since it doesn't seem to have an intrinsic one, since $G$ and $UB$ also don't) by taking as objects the morphisms of graphs $A: G \to UB$ and as arrows the transformations $\tau: A \to A' $ defined by $\tau_c:A(c) \to A'(c)$ **if such arrows exist in** $UB$. After this, $\operatorname{Grph}(G,UB)$ has only a graph structure, so I took the final structure to be the free category associated with that graph... I tried to follow this approach for a bit to see if I could get some natural functors out of those classes and then construct a natural transformation between the two functors from the bijections, but this seems rather farfetched to me, and seems to have a lot of problems, and so I couldn't get a conclusion out of this.

Is my interpretation wrong?

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance :)

Comment: You should be looking for functors $\textbf{Cat} \to \textbf{Set}$. After all, we usually only speak of bijections between sets.

Comment: I thought about that, but figured it couldn't be that because the class was too big

Comment: The categories in question are small, so there is no problem.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you! I hadn't noticed that for some reason. I'll try it out

Comment: Thank you again, I figured it out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,A' : G \to U(B)$ be two graph morphisms (which you can also see as diagrams of shape $G$ in $B$). A morphism $A \to A'$ is by definition a family of morphisms $A(v) \to A'(v)$, for each vertex $v$ of $G$, such that for each edge $v \to w$ in $G$ the diagram
$$\begin{array}{cc}
A(v) & \rightarrow & A'(v) \\ 
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
A(w) & \rightarrow & A'(w)
\end{array}$$
of morphisms in $B$ commutes. You can easily construct compositions of such morphisms and show that $\mathrm{Graph}(G,U(B))$ is, indeed, a category. Notice the similarity to the notion of a natural transformation. This can be used to show that the bijection

$$\mathrm{Cat}(C_G,B) \to \mathrm{Graph}(G,U(B)),~ F \mapsto F|_G$$

extends to an isomorphism of categories. The verification of naturality is trivial.

Comment: But how can you speak of composition in this case, since the the arrows $A(v) \to A'(v)$ and the others are just arrows in a graph, where there is no composition?

Comment: No, they are morphisms in $B$. And $B$ is a category. You can consider the example $ G = (\bullet \to \bullet)$, convince yourself that $\mathrm{Graph}(G,U(B)) \cong \mathrm{Mor}(B)$.

Comment: If $A$ and $A'$ are morphisms of graphs, then by definition in Mac Lane's book, they're arrows in $U(B)$

Comment: Yes, I suppose that makes sense

Comment: Arrows in $U(B)$ are arrows in $B$, by definition. You can compose them (in $B$ of course, not in the graph $U(B)$).

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you for your answer